# In what scenarios can auto storage class be used in functions?

Tags: c, function

```
auto void foo(void)
{
    printf("test");
}
```

Let's say I wrote this function, In what possible cases can I use auto storage class opposed to static or extern?

Answer (score 1):

From [C11 6.9.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p4):

> **6.9.1 Function definitions**
>
> ...
>
> ```
>       function-definition:
>              declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-listopt compound-statement
> ```
>
> ...
>
> 4 The storage-class specifier, if any, in the declaration specifiers shall be either extern or static.

Using `auto` as the storage class specifier for function definition is a constraint violation. The code is invalid, behavior is undefined. I believe compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.

> In what possible cases can I use `auto` storage class [with functions] opposed to `static` or `extern`?

Never.

Comment: I see, it does compie in gcc with a warning. So if it compiles, with a warning ofc, is it the same as a static function

Comment: No, it's not the same. The code is invalid. The behavior is undefined. I believe gcc just ignores the invalid storage specifier.